# ¿Cómo saber qué elemento generó un evento?

Tags: javascript, eventos

Verán, lo que necesito es saber cuando un elemento ha activado un evento, el tiene su respectivo EventListener, pero son varios elementos los que tiene ese Listener, entonces ¿como se cual de todos los elementos fue el que activo el evento?

```
(function(elementos){
for (var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
    elementos[i].addEventListener("click", marcar(), false);
}
})(document.getElementsByTagName("a"));
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="nota">
        <span><h1>Tareas</h1></span>
        <div class="actividades">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Levantarme</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cepillarme</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Comer</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bañarme</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Como ven les paso por parametro a la funcion una serie de elementos "a" , a los cuales a cada uno con un "for" les añado un EventListener, entonces si yo quisiera saber cual de todos los elementos "a" activó el evento, ¿que podria hacer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para poder identificar que elemento disparó un evento puedes hacer uso de la delegación de eventos:

- Los elementos de los cuales quieres identificar quien disparó un evento necesitan estar dentro de una etiqueta padre
- A la etiqueta padre la obtenemos y asignamos a una variable
- A la variable que contiene dicha etiqueta padre le agregas un listener en el evento `click` por ejemplo
- Ahora para poder identificar dentro de ese *contexto* a quien se le dió click evaluamos el contenido que nos da el evento a través de la propiedad `target` que nos regresaría una amplia cantidad de información; donde para saberlo puedes usar:

  - **`className`**
  - **`id`**
  - **`innerText`**
  - etc.
- Le ventaja de esto es que el evento se evalúa en una etiqueta padre y se observa quien de los hijos lo generó con lo que evitarías tener que hacer uso de ciclos para estar iterando el total de ellos

**Ejemplo**

```html
    <ul class="contenedor-listas">
        <a class="uno" href="#">Enlace 1</a>
        <a class="uno" href="#">Enlace 2</a>
        <a class="uno" href="#">Enlace 3</a>
        <a class="uno" href="#">Enlace 4</a>
        <a class="uno" href="#">Enlace 5</a>
    </ul>
      <p></p>
    <script>
        let contenedorListas = document.querySelector(".contenedor-listas")
        let parrafo = document.querySelector("p")
        
        contenedorListas.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
          parrafo.innerText = `Quien disparó el evento fue: ${event.target.innerText}`
        })
    </script>
```

Si quieres ver toda la información que puedes obtener, te recomiendo que imprimas en consola por medio de la siguiente instrucción:

```
console.log(event.target);
```

Dentro del contexto del código provisto

**Documentos de Referencias**

- [event target](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/target)
- [¿Cómo funciona la delegación de eventos en JS?](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)
- [Delegación de eventos en JavaScript](https://ed.team/blog/como-usar-la-delegacion-de-eventos-en-javascript)

Comment: Gracias bro, me funciono de maravilla =)