# ¿Cómo puedo saber que boton se pulso en JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```html
<div>
<a id="eliminar-1" ..>Eliminar</a>
<a id="eliminar-2" ..>Eliminar</a>
</div>
```

Si tengo muchos elementos que por id comiencen con `eliminar-`, ¿cómo puedo diferenciarlos en Javascript? Puesto que con la libreria de JQuery se puede hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
$(a[id^="eliminar-"]).on('click', () => {})
```

Tengo esta duda, puesto que dentro de un archivo, genero una lista de grupos de personas y tengo que eliminar un grupo en especifico.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo saber qué elemento generó un evento?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/347316/c%c3%b3mo-saber-qu%c3%a9-elemento-gener%c3%b3-un-evento)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para añadir eventos en JS tienes que usar el método `addEventListener`.

El callback que se pasa al metodo `.addEventListener` recibe un parámetro que tiene todos los datos sobre el evento que se ha producido, es decir, donde se ha clicado, la referencia de ese elemento y muchas propiedades más.

Este parámetro conocido como `event` tiene una propiedad que es el `target` y que contiene la referencia al elemento que ha se ha clicado. Con esto puedes saber que botón se ha clicado accediendo el atributo `id` del botón.

Puedes seleccionar los botones con `querySelectorAll` y añadir el listener para el evento click.

[Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event)

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('a[id^="eliminar-"]');
btns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log(e.target.id)
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
<a id="eliminar-1" ..>Eliminar</a>
<a id="eliminar-2" ..>Eliminar</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Claro, esa seria la forma de hacerlo por Jquery, pero existe la forma de hacerlo con javascript puro ?

Comment: ya pues  no entendí que era en javascript puro. Ahora lo cambio

Comment: he actualizado la respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, de verdad me ha servido mucho !