# Obtener el valor de un radio button en JS

Tags: javascript, radiobutton

Tengo que hacer un ejercicio bastante basico en js pero no logro resolverlo
el ejercicio es 1) Crea dos radiobuttons, cuando uno de ellos se seleccione que muestre un mensaje diciendo que opción se seleccionó.
mi codigo html es este y tambien tengo que utilizar la propiedad checked

```
 <h1>Indica que medio de transporte desea usar</h1>
    <form id="transporte">
      <input type="radio" name="transporte" id="Auto"> Auto </input> <br>
      <input type="radio" name="transporte" id="Bicicleta"> Bicicleta</input>
```

---

gracias yo estaba intentando algo asi

```
<body>
      <h1>Indica que medio de transporte desea usar</h1>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" value="auto" id="auto" onclick="transporte"> Auto </input> <br>
      <input type="radio" value="bicicleta" id="bicicleta" onclick="transporte"> Bicicleta</input>
      

    </form>

    <script >

        function transporte(){
        var auto = document.getElementById("auto");
        var bicicleta = document.getElementById("bicicleta");
        
        if(auto.checked == true){
            alert("El medio de trasnporte que eligio es: "+ auto.value);
        }else if(bicicleta.checked == true){
            alert("El medio de trasnporte que eligio es: "+ bicicleta.value);
        }

        }
     
     
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Podrías agregar que has intentado?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo saber qué elemento generó un evento?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/347316/c%c3%b3mo-saber-qu%c3%a9-elemento-gener%c3%b3-un-evento)

Answer (score 2):

A ver si entendi bien, intenta hacer algo como esto, aclarando que agregue el atributo **`value`** a cada **`radio`** para poder extraer el valor del radio seleccionado

```js
let opcion1 = document.querySelector('#Auto');
let opcion2 = document.querySelector('#Bicicleta');


document.querySelector('#transporte').addEventListener('change',()=>{
    if (opcion1.checked){
      alert('La opcion seleccionada es:'+' '+opcion1.value);
    }else if(opcion2.checked){
      alert('La opcion seleccionada es:'+' '+opcion2.value);
    }
})
```

```html
 <h1>Indica que medio de transporte desea usar</h1>
    <form id="transporte">
        <input type="radio" name="transporte" id="Auto" value="Auto"> Auto </input> <br>
       <input type="radio" name="transporte" id="Bicicleta" value="Bicicleta"> Bicicleta</input>
    </form>
```

Comment: Hola amigo!, es una critica constructiva, no he ejecutado tu codigo, pero asi funcione bien ten en cuenta que no le hacemos ningun bien al que hizo la pregunta si nada mas resolvemos el problema sin que este haya dado evidencia primero de haberlo intentado, en este caso no se ha visto que el usuario haya hecho nada mas halla de eso, por ende normalmente se espera para responder hasta que el usuario de pistas de que realmente ha intentado realizar el mismo lo que ha preguntado. este tipo de recomendaciones las encontraras en varias preguntas similares.

Comment: Los usuarios antiguos o "veteranos" por eso evitan el responder sin mas a la pregunta, puesto que la idea es a ayudar al usuario a aprender, y no hacerle todo sin mas, sin embargo se aprecia el esfuerzo, en mi caso no votare ni positivo ni negativo ya que eres nuevo, pero entonces te invito a leer [answer].

Comment: Como detectas que algo sucedió en tu form??  precisamente con el evento change, cuando se inicia la aplicacion no hay ningun radio seleccionado, cuando el usuario selecciona el radio ahi surge un cambio y se evalua que presiono el usuario.

Comment: Jajjaja acabo de ver tu nombre, un idolo, ummmm ese cambio no necesariamente tiene que ser el form, ten en cuenta que el evento click tambien sirve para saber si se clico en un elemento. en este caso te sirve porque es un elemento radio.

Comment: Nunca especificó que al presionar un boton detectará que radio se seleccionó de ahi el evento change, si hubiera sido asi, entonces la respuesta que hubiera dado es: agrega un evento de tipo click al boton, o bien al radio, pero al inicio dijo que se tenia que usar cheked. Lo bonito de la programacion es que hay muchas soluciones para un solo problema.

Comment: De hecho estoy errado, es muchisimo mejor usar el evento change, ya que los radio tienen ese evento, y te escuchan justo el momento en el que ha habido un cambio en el radio si estan ligados, asi que... es mejor que se use un evento change en los radios que un evento click

Comment: Todo mundo aconseja sobre como responder, pero por que no brindar la respuesta si ya la tienes, yo doy por hecho que ya intento por su cuenta hacer las cosas, y como no pudo se metió a un blog de ayuda. Imaginate que busques ayuda y las respuestas que encuentras es: investiga por tu cuenta. Vaya liada.

Comment: @NikolaTesla es cierto, aunque... muchas veces no pasa asi, algunas ocasiones la persona simplemente se metio a preguntar directamente por pereza de no pensar, y es ahi cuando aplica aquello, por eso nosotros esperamos a que la persona edite el codigo para saber si realmente lo intento, ya que realmente para saber si alguien lo intento no necesitamos exactamente codigo, por ejemplo, dinos: ahh haciendo esto encontre esto o mirando por ahi encontre esto pero ningun resultado satisface lo que necesito, eso es diferente. es decir, hay evidencia de que algo intento

Comment: Bueno, ya iré agarrando experiencia en esto, y según mi criterio responderé como crea que sea correcto, me da igual las votaciones, estoy aqui para ayudar y no para ser popular, soy partidario de que el conocimiento solo tiene valor cuando se comparte. Saludos cordiales desde México.

Comment: @NikolaTesla Es chévere ver algo asi, sin embargo piensalo de esta manera: el usuario debe desarrollar su logica, si nosotros lo ayudamos asi sin mas sin una investigacion detras es como simplemente matarle la logica, en vez de ello considero que lo mas optimo (segun mi opinion) es dejar informacion util primero en los comentarios antes de dar una posible respuesta, pues con esa informacion ella misma puede investigar y quiza responder a su propia pregunta, o tambien si no encuentra lo que busca por lo menos editarla y mostrarnos el esfuerzo que hizo.

Comment: De esta manera nosotros podemos explicarle ahi si que esta haciendo mal y el porque tiene esos errores, y asi corregir su codigo o mostrarle cual es el problema e irla orientando, esto se hace, recalco es para que el usuario desarrolle su logica, es imprescindible cuando eres programador que no dependas de fuentes externas para poder arreglar un problema. o que dependas pero en lo minimo, que sea literalmente solo un 10% de las vecez y pues ese 10% normalmente se ajusta a lo que la mayoria de personas pregunta aqui en stackoverflow, preguntas que no logran encontrarle solucion

Answer (score 0):

Intenta realizar algo como esto: te dejo una guia para que aprendas mas sobre

```
document.querySellectorAll();
```

[Guia sobre querySellectorAll](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9JXBVeZWQrA)

```js
/*la variable opciones esta lista 
para que agregues mas radios y siga
funcionando sin problema*/

let opciones = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');

/*Agregamos un evento a tu formulario 
para detectar cuando algo suceda*/

document.querySelector('#transporte').addEventListener('change',()=>{

 // recorremos opciones ya que dentro hay una lista de nodos
    opciones.forEach(opcion =>{
    
 //si la opcion recorrida esta seleccionada mostramos esa opcion
        if(opcion.checked){
            alert('la opcion seleccionada es:'+' '+opcion.value);
        }
    })
})
```

```html
    <h1>Indica que medio de transporte desea usar</h1>
    <form id="transporte">
        <input type="radio" name="transporte" id="Auto" value="Auto"> Auto </input> <br>
       <input type="radio" name="transporte" id="Bicicleta" value="Bicicleta"> Bicicleta</input>
    </form>
```

Comment: Porque hay dos respuestas? xd